# Resizing tabs in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I have created 4 tabs containing 4 images at the screen bottom in BlackBerry 9700. I want to know how do I resize these tabs dynamically to suit other blackberry screens. When I test the same code in 9800, I can see only 3 tabs and the fourth one goes out of visibility. I know resizing image dynamically for Background screens but how to do the same for tabs or image buttons?

Comment: Are you using a `ToolBar`? If yes, take a look [here](http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.in/2011/05/implementing-tab-control-in-blackberry.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to Resize your all `Tabbar` images depends on `Device width` using  `ResizeBitmap` Class.

Ex: `Bitmap tab = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("Your image path")
Bitmap tab1 = ResizeBitmap.resizeBitmap(tab, Display.getWidth()/4, tab.getHeight());`

Resize all your four images like above. Than add four images to your `Horizontalfield` manager. Override `sublayout()` method and set its width & height.

Now you can see all tab perfect in all device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call different  images based on the screen resolutions instead of resizing because of better image quality.

You have to load images based on screen resolution by using methods

```
Display.getWidth();

Display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

If its for tab-bar, you need a fixed height and width dependent on device width, you can scale your images to:

```
int width=Display.getWidth()/4;
int height=Display.getHeight()/6;// or some fixed height, independent of device height.
```